# Problem importing Eclipse Launcher file into Intellij

Tags: java, eclipse, intellij-idea

I have imported the Eclipse Launcher file into Intellij using **import with Eclipser**. But the classpaths are missing into Intellij launcher. 
I was wondering how can I import classpaths into Intellij Launcher as I can do in Eclipse launcher.
I am unable to run the java application.

**Eclipse Launcher File:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<launchConfiguration type="org.eclipse.jdt.launching.localJavaApplication">
<listAttribute key="org.eclipse.debug.core.MAPPED_RESOURCE_PATHS">
<listEntry value="/abcdExtension"/>
</listAttribute>
<listAttribute key="org.eclipse.debug.core.MAPPED_RESOURCE_TYPES">
<listEntry value="4"/>
</listAttribute>
<booleanAttribute key="org.eclipse.jdt.launching.ATTR_USE_START_ON_FIRST_THREAD" value="true"/>
<listAttribute key="org.eclipse.jdt.launching.CLASSPATH">
<listEntry value="&lt;?xml version=&quot;1.0&quot; encoding=&quot;UTF-8&quot; standalone=&quot;no&quot;?&gt;&#13;&#10;&lt;runtimeClasspathEntry containerPath=&quot;org.eclipse.jdt.launching.JRE_CONTAINER/org.eclipse.jdt.internal.debug.ui.launcher.StandardVMType/jdk1.8.0_77&quot; path=&quot;1&quot; type=&quot;4&quot;/&gt;&#13;&#10;"/>
<listEntry value="&lt;?xml version=&quot;1.0&quot; encoding=&quot;UTF-8&quot; standalone=&quot;no&quot;?&gt;&#13;&#10;&lt;runtimeClasspathEntry path=&quot;3&quot; projectName=&quot;abcdExtension&quot; type=&quot;1&quot;/&gt;&#13;&#10;"/>
<listEntry value="&lt;?xml version=&quot;1.0&quot; encoding=&quot;UTF-8&quot; standalone=&quot;no&quot;?&gt;&#13;&#10;&lt;runtimeClasspathEntry containerPath=&quot;org.eclipse.m2e.MAVEN2_CLASSPATH_CONTAINER&quot; path=&quot;3&quot; type=&quot;4&quot;/&gt;&#13;&#10;"/>
<listEntry value="&lt;?xml version=&quot;1.0&quot; encoding=&quot;UTF-8&quot; standalone=&quot;no&quot;?&gt;&#13;&#10;&lt;runtimeClasspathEntry internalArchive=&quot;/abcd-package/src/resources&quot; path=&quot;3&quot; type=&quot;2&quot;/&gt;&#13;&#10;"/>
<listEntry value="&lt;?xml version=&quot;1.0&quot; encoding=&quot;UTF-8&quot; standalone=&quot;no&quot;?&gt;&#13;&#10;&lt;runtimeClasspathEntry internalArchive=&quot;/abcdPackage/src/resources/Custom.jar&quot; path=&quot;3&quot; type=&quot;2&quot;/&gt;&#13;&#10;"/>
</listAttribute>
<stringAttribute key="org.eclipse.jdt.launching.CLASSPATH_PROVIDER" value="org.eclipse.m2e.launchconfig.classpathProvider"/>
<booleanAttribute key="org.eclipse.jdt.launching.DEFAULT_CLASSPATH" value="false"/>
<stringAttribute key="org.eclipse.jdt.launching.MAIN_TYPE" value="com.abcd.Main"/>
<stringAttribute key="org.eclipse.jdt.launching.MODULE_NAME" value="abcdExtension"/>
<stringAttribute key="org.eclipse.jdt.launching.PROGRAM_ARGUMENTS" value="TraceLevel=5"/>
<stringAttribute key="org.eclipse.jdt.launching.PROJECT_ATTR" value="abcdExtension"/>
<stringAttribute key="org.eclipse.jdt.launching.SOURCE_PATH_PROVIDER" value="org.eclipse.m2e.launchconfig.sourcepathProvider"/>
</launchConfiguration>
```

**When Importing to Intellij with Eclipser:-**

```
<component name="ProjectRunConfigurationManager">
  <configuration default="false" name="Main" type="Application" factoryName="Application">
    <option name="ALTERNATIVE_JRE_PATH" value="1.8" />
    <option name="ALTERNATIVE_JRE_PATH_ENABLED" value="true" />
    <option name="MAIN_CLASS_NAME" value="com.abcd.Main" />
    <module name="abcdExtension" />
    <option name="PROGRAM_PARAMETERS" value="TraceLevel=5" />
    <option name="WORKING_DIRECTORY" value="$MODULE_DIR$" />
    <method v="2">
      <option name="Make" enabled="true" />
    </method>
  </configuration>
</component>
```